# How to add a new App in an Android build?

Tags: android, customization

I have implemented a small application in Android and I want to add it in my own customised build. I included it under `/packages/apps`. However, when I build the image I can't find the package in my system, despite the fact that others such as the Camera and other apps exist.

The Android.mk file is OK but it looks like I'm missing somewhere in a make file or a script where to compile my own app and copy it into the system apps.

Could anyone provide me any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the app's folder path to one of the .mk files. I dont remember the mk file's name right now. But you can search in the source for "*.mk" . Search under frameworks too. Check core.mk.

Comment: Thanks! That's the problem... I can't find the right .mk file. I'm not sure whether this is under vendor, device or packages...

Comment: search under frameworks too. Check core.mk. Do a search for all .mk files. check every file for /packages/apps/.. paths. Add your app path to such file..

Comment: I just did a grep to /packages/apps and specific packages such as Camera and couldn't find anything. I did the Android.mk in the similar fashion to Camera app and others and it did compile (because I included an error on purpose to see if that was going through it). The problem is... when does it copy the output of this to the final product build?

Comment: Sorry for not replying earlier but yeah, core.mk is the place! Thanks!